# Insertar campos adicionales en table Pivot - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, insert

```
**Hola estimados amigos, agradecería su apoyo en lo siguiente;**
```

**Tema principal:** imposibilidad de Insertar campos adicionales en la
tabla pivot, estoy utilizando laravel 8, con metodo Attach, tengo
presente las convenciones de laravel para la definicion de sus modelos,
a continuacion detallo lo siguiente:

```
 **Modelo de la tabla Period**


 public function indicators(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Indicator::class)
                ->withPivot('amount','observation')
                ->withTimestamps();
} 

    **Modelo de la tabla indicator**


{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Period::class)
            ->withPivot('amount','observation')
            ->withTimestamps();
                
}
```

Tengo la funcion definida en el metodo store, que inserta los id de las llaves foraneos de las tablas relacionadas muchos a muchos, muestro el codigo.

```
public function store(StoreRecordRequest $request)
{
    
    $period = Period::create($request->all());
    
    if($request->indicators)
    return $request;        
    $period->indicators()->attach($request->indicators);
    return redirect()->route('guest.periods.edit', $period);
    
    
    //return $request
}

   *EL tema principal es que no he podido insertar registros adicionales que vienen cuyos campos en la tabla pivot son amount y observation*, muestro la migracion respeectiva 

 Schema::create('indicator_period', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('indicator_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('period_id');
        $table->integer('amount')->nullable();
        $table->string('observation')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('indicator_id')->references('id')->on('indicators');
        $table->foreign('period_id')->references('id')->on('periods');
        
        $table->timestamps();
  **Intente hacer la insercion de la siguiente manera pero no funciono**


  $period->indicators()->attach($request->indicators, ['amount'=> $amount, 'observation'=> $observation]);
```

*Agradezco puedan apoyarme*

Comment: El código debe ir como texto

Comment: Ya lo modifique amigo Betam, ayduame por favor